# MKDirectionsResponse: error, Directions not available. (USA)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mapkit, clgeocoder

For learning purposes I'm trying to develop an app which will show directions to a specific point on a MKMapView.
However, the DirectionsResponse gives me the following error everytime, no matter the address:

```
2013-12-28 17:52:23.100 routingApp[378:70b] ERROR
2013-12-28 17:52:23.102 routingApp[378:70b] Directions Not Available
```

I only have a View Controller with a map view and the following code:

routingAppViewController.h

```
@interface routingAppViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MKPlacemark *destination;
@end
```

routingAppViewController.m

```
#import "routingAppViewController.h"

@interface routingAppViewController ()
@end

@implementation routingAppViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *Location = @"385 Mid Avenue Weston";
_mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
[self getDirections:Location];


}

-(void)getDirections:(NSString *)address{


CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:address
             completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                 // Check for returned placemarks
                 if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                     CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                     // Create a MLPlacemark and add it to the map view
                     MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
                     [self.mapView addAnnotation:placemark];
                     _destination = placemark;
                 }
             }];

MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:_destination];


MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
request.source = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];

request.destination = mapItem;
request.requestsAlternateRoutes = NO;

MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"ERROR");
         NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
     } else {
         [self showRoute:response];
     }
 }];


}

-(void)showRoute:(MKDirectionsResponse *)response
{
for (MKRoute *route in response.routes)
{
    [_mapView
     addOverlay:route.polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];

    for (MKRouteStep *step in route.steps)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", step.instructions);
    }
}
}

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay
{
MKPolylineRenderer *renderer =
[[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
renderer.lineWidth = 5.0;
return renderer;
}
```

The error is given in the `getDirections` method.
I googled it and mostly the error means that the direction service is not available for this country. However i'm using an USA address, so I can't see why it's not working.

The annotation is added correctly and my location is set to "Apple".
Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `completionHandler` block called by `geocodeAddressString` is asynchronous.

This means that the code that tries to get the directions from the current location to `_destination` runs *immediately* after the `geocodeAddressString` line and executes *before* `_destination` is set.

So when `mapItem` is created, it is using `_destination` still set to `nil` (the geocoder block hasn't finished and set `_destination` yet).

Trying to get directions from the current location to `nil` results in the get directions error.

The simplest fix is to move the code that gets the directions request inside the `completionHandler` block of `geocodeAddressString` (right after `_destination` is actually set):

```
                 [self.mapView addAnnotation:placemark];
                 _destination = placemark;

                 //move the code that gets the directions here,
                 //inside this block...

                 MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] init...
                 ...
                 [directions calculateDirections...
             }
```

Comment: That's some great thinking work, I would have never come to think of that my self. Everything is working now, thanks!